# Magento 2 checkout stuck on loading after filling billing information

Tags: magento2

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return $parent.elems() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return getTemplate() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return (JSON.parse($parent.options).length > 0) }"
Message: Unable to process binding "mageInit: function(){return {'collapsible':{'openedState':'active'}} }"
```

[image]

Comment: Please fill email id value and try.

Comment: Whether you can able to fix the issue. Could you please tell the root cause of this issue. I am also facing the same issue